# Google Chrome bookmarks issue

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have been having a strange issue with the Google Chrome bookmarks bar.  Every time I install Google Chrome and sync with my GMail account, I get dozens of bookmarks folders into my bookmarks.  Its just folders and subfolders of my one bookmarks folder repeating.  You can see the issue below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I delete these folders, but every time I install a new instance of Chrome, they all come back.  I dont understand why they keep coming back.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: It might be helpful to revert to the old bookmarks manager interface.  To do so: go to chrome://flags.  Search on page for *bookmarks*.  Toggle "Enable Material Design bookmarks" off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Chrome Bookmarks Reappearing

1. Backup your Chrome Bookmarks by going to **`chrome://bookmarks/`**, click on  [image] and then select **Export Bookmarks**
2. Sign onto **Gmail** and then go to https://chrome.google.com/sync and press the **Reset Sync** option.
3. Now sign out of **Gmail**, check Chrome **Bookmarks** and delete any that exist and close **Chrome**.
4. Open **Chrome** and check **Bookmarks** to confirm they are gone, and then sign onto **Gmail** and check **Bookmarks** again and confirm they are still gone.

---

### Further Resources

- [Chrome Bookmarks keep coming back](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/haFHUAEPKpk)